# Symfony Doctrine Cache Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine

How can I cache a particular field for an entity? For example let's say I have the following field:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Site", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="site_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $site;
```

The referenced Site entities never change, they are just static entries in the database, obviously there is no point going to the database for them.

Answer (score 0):

[Second level cache](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/second-level-cache.html#association-cache-definition) was the answer